# Java Boolean... How to keep pointing to same reference despite Boolean value changing

Tags: java, reference, boolean

There are similar questions out there, but I found none quite as specific to this problem.

I have several classes/objects that need to know a state Boolean of one common object. But giving each of them the reference to the Boolean is really a reference to a True or False value... not to the state Boolean... thus the moment the state value is changed, the objects don't get that updated value, but instead are still referencing the previous false or true value.

Example code:

```
public class State {
    protected Boolean state = true;
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        State state = new State();
        Boolean ref1 = state.state;
        state.state = false;
        System.out.println("state.state = " + state.state);
        System.out.println("ref1 = " + ref1);

        ref1 = true;
        System.out.println("state.state = " + state.state);
        System.out.println("ref1 = " + ref1);


    }
}
```

Results:

```
state.state = false
ref1 = true
state.state = false
ref1 = true
```

Note: I am specifically avoiding a method call to the common state object, due to the high speed repetitive execution of my code (every millisecond counts).

Is there a way to pass a reference to the state Boolean without losing updates? A special wrapper class I don't know about? Should I build my own?

Comment: It's a bit of a hack but if you pass an array (size 1) of boolean and then toggle the true/false in `array[0]` all classes that have a reference to the array will see the bool change

Comment: You can use `state.state=true` to change it and access `state.state`.

Comment: Just access `state.state` instead.

Comment: @CaiusJard Nice hack! Only bummer is the array would need to be public or protected in order to access it, in which case I should just go directly to state.state, as dan1st and Unmitigated suggested.

Comment: The `Boolean` class is a wrapper around a `boolean` value. You have designed your `State` as a wrapper around a `Boolean`. If “every millisecond counts”, don’t use a wrapper around a wrapper but just change the type of `state` from `Boolean` to `boolean`. Then, instead of passing a reference to an immutable wrapper around a `boolean` (the `Boolean`), pass a reference to a mutable wrapper around a `boolean` (the `State`).

Answer (score 0):

```
State state = new State();
State ref1 = state;

state.state = false;
System.out.println("state.state = " + state.state);
System.out.println("ref1.state = " + ref1.state);

state.state = true;
System.out.println("state.state = " + state.state);
System.out.println("ref1.state = " + ref1.state);

// This is the reason you need to protect the
// `state` from being modified by external parties
ref1.state = false;
System.out.println("state.state = " + state.state);
System.out.println("ref1.state = " + ref1.state);
```

Results should be:

```
state.state = false
ref1.state = false
state.state = true
ref1.state = true
state.state = false
ref1.state = false
```

Wrapping via a getter will help prevent needing to worry multiple places of your code having ability to update the `state`.

```
public class State {
    private Boolean state = false;
    public Boolean getState() {
        return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. While this is the standard Object Oriented Programming way to do it... it does require a method call, which as I said in my original post would be too costly for my application. (this will run every millisecond, so every method call is costly).